# Drag-and-Drop an Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with 6 labels 4 of them have png Images in them. I have it set up so the user can drag one of the 4 images into label5 and label6 would give them a message to tell them which of the 4 they picked
I have the drag drop part working but cannot figure out what code I need to tell them which was picked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Drag_Drop_Tester2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Image img1 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Red.png");
    Image img2 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Blue.png");
    Image img3 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Green.png");
    Image img4 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Orange.png");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DD_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPic = (Label)sender;
        lblPic.DoDragDrop(lblPic.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void DD_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void DD_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPic = (Label)sender;
        Graphics g = lblPic.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage((Image)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap)), new Point(0, 0));

        if ("code that goes here")
            lblMsg.Text = "You picked red";
        else
            lblMsg.Text = "I can't decide what you picked";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't expect someone to solve your problem without some context, (even code) to fix your problem.

Comment: Write your code and we will try to solve the error that you have in the code sample.

Comment: Okay here is the code it just allows the user to drag an image from 1 label to another. I have an if else at the bottom which is where I need help.

Comment: @Mark Hall this is a windows forms application, I'm just trying to learn how to use drag and drop with an image here. This is a tester program to see if I can't get it to work. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out:

```
If (sender == label1)

lblMsg.Text = "You Picked Red";
```

I was making it harder then it needed to be

Answer (score 0):

What you posted will work but you can also add a Tag to the image, that way you are not dependent on the Label's name to determine what image was dropped. See if something like this will work for you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Image img1 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Red.png");
    Image img2 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Blue.png");
    Image img3 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Green.png");
    Image img4 = Image.FromFile("Peg_Orange.png");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        img1.Tag = 1;
        img2.Tag = 2;
        img3.Tag = 3;
        img4.Tag = 4;
        label1.Image = img1;
        label2.Image = img2;
        label3.Image = img3;
        label4.Image = img4;

    }

    private void DD_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPic = (Label)sender;
        lblPic.DoDragDrop(lblPic.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void DD_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void DD_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPic = (Label)sender;
        Graphics g = lblPic.CreateGraphics();
        var image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        var index = (int)image.Tag;
        g.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));

        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        g.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();

    } 

}
```

Comment: Very interesting will have to try that